# HashMap code not working as cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, hashmap

Creating a hashmap with worker as class. The key is worker ID (integer) and the value is list string(names of the workers) when I execute the following code workers.put.etc as below it says...

method put in interface java.util.Map cannot be applied to given types;
requited:java.lang.integer.java.util.List; found int java lang string; reason actual argument java.lang.string cannot be converted etc etc

**
import java.util.*;**

```
 public class Workers
    {
      private Map<Integer, List<String>>workers;

      public Workers() {
          workers = new HashMap<Integer,List <String>>();
      }
      public void populateMap() {
            workers.put("10", "Tim Jones");
            workers.put("11", "Sarah Sands");


      }

       public void printMap() {     
        for (Map.Entry entry : workers.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "
                        + entry.getValue());

        } 
      }
      public void printMapValue(List <String> key) {
            if(workers.containsKey(key)) {
                System.out.println(workers.get(key));
            } else {
                System.out.println(key + " does not exist in the map");
            }
        }
      public void addMapEntry(int key, List<String> values){
          workers.put(key,values);

    }
    }
```

Comment: " cannot be converted etc etc" I'm sure that's not the actual message. Please add the full message.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a driver and you didn't include the actual error.  This makes it hard to determine where your error is occurring.  Nonetheless, the `printMapValue` methods takes a `List<String>` argument.  This is the value type for your `Map`.  But you are treating it as the key within the method, which is supposed to be an `Integer`.  That's not going to work.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to put a `String` value in to a map that has a `List<String>` value type. You should wrap this string with a list before attempting to add it to list. With Java 8's `computeIfAbsent`, this is actually quite elegant, and you don't have to mess around with the complexity of checking if the list already exists or not:

```java
workers.computeIfAbset(10, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("Tim Jones");
```

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comments, you could of course do this without Java 8's APIs if you check the key's existence yourself:

```java
int key = 10;
List<String> tmp = workers.get(key);
if (tmp !=  null) {
    tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    workers.put(key, tmp);
}
tmp.add("Tim Jones");
```

Comment: how do I go about doing that without Java 8s method

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put a String in the map value but is a list. check this code:

```
 public class Workers
{
  private Map<Integer, List<String>>workers;

  public Workers() {
      workers = new HashMap<Integer,List <String>>();
  }

 private populateMap(Map<Integer,List <String>> map, Integer workerId, String value) {
     if (! map.contains(workerId)){
         map.put(workerId, new ArrayList<String>());
     } 
     map.get(workerId).add(value);
 }


  public void populateMap() {
        populateMap(map,"10", "Tim Jones");
        populateMap(map,"11", "Sarah Sands");


  }

   public void printMap() {     
    for (Map.Entry entry : workers.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "
                    + entry.getValue());

    } 
  }
  public void printMapValue(List <String> key) {
        if(workers.containsKey(key)) {
            System.out.println(workers.get(key));
        } else {
            System.out.println(key + " does not exist in the map");
        }
    }
  public void addMapEntry(int key, List<String> values){
      workers.put(key,values);

}
}
```

Comment: so I need to write a public instance method to populate the map with some test data .The method should take no arguments and should need no user intervention, in particular it should not involve the use of dialogues. All the data must be written into the code of the method.

Comment: it could be private, the important point is that you have a Map [Integer, list(string)]  if you use the put with a string will fail cause a list of strings are expected. The method it inserts the string in the list and in case that it's the first time it sets a new list. or you'll get a nullpointer

Comment: as Mureinik say you can use the java8  Map method computeIfAbsent() to handle this.